# Is there any program emulator of Series 60 1st edition Symbian 6.1 phone for PC?

Tags: symbian

I need to run .app program (or packed in .sis) written for old good Symbian 6.1 (not MIDP!) but I haven't found it yet. Is there any emulator in SDK and where to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run app files (compiled for Symbian) in Windows Emulator.
If you have the source code and you manage to find some old 6.1 SDK then you can recompile it for Emulator, but otherwise its easier to find some old phone where to run it